# The limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2 + 1/n\right)^{n}$

Tags: calculus

How can one show that
$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(2 + {1 \over n}\right)^n}$ ?.

I am trying to shoehorn the definition of $e$ somewhere but fruitlessly so.

Comment: $$2^n \leqslant \left(2+\frac1n\right)^n \leqslant 3^n$$

Comment: $\large\verb*\displaystyle*$ is not allowed in the main title.

Comment: @user119114 : how can one show that what?  What are you trying to show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 2^n \left(1 + \frac{1/2}{n}\right)^n \sim 2^n \sqrt{e}$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 19):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(2 + \frac 1n\right)^n\ge\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{1}{n}$ will asymptotically approach 0,  the limit inside the parenthesis will go to 2.  In turn, the limit of $2^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity is infinity as that function increases without bound.

Comment: Be very careful here with taking limits piecemeal. It doesn't cost you here, but it usually does.

Answer (score -2):

Applying L'Hopital $\lim(2+\frac{1}{n})^n=\lim(e^{\log(2+\frac{1}{n})n})=e^{\lim(\log(2+\frac{1}{n})/n^{-1})}$  the exponent will blow up.